# Can the convolution of a $L^1$ integrable function and a sequence of weakly $L^2$ convergent functions converge in $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

$K$ is a $L^1$ integrable function,  $\{\phi_n\}$ is  a sequence of weakly $L^2$ convergent functions to $\phi$ and $supp(\phi_n)\subseteq [-1,1]$.Is the convolution $f_n(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}K(x-y)\phi_n(y)dy$ convergent to $f(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}K(x-y)\phi(y)dy$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

I only got that $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in $L^2$, I don't know how to strengthen it.

First we know $||f_n||_2\leq ||K||_1\cdot ||\phi_n||_2<\infty,||f||_2\leq ||K||_1\cdot ||\phi||_2<\infty $, so $f_n, f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

For any $g\in L^2, \int K(x-y)g(x)dx \in L^2,$ by the weakly convergence of $\phi_n$, we get $\int (\int K(x-y)g(x)dx) \phi_n(y)dy \rightarrow \int (\int K(x-y)g(x)dx) \phi(y)dy$.

so $\int f_n g=\int (\int K(x-y)g(x)dx) \phi_n(y)dy\rightarrow \int fg=\int (\int K(x-y)g(x)dx) \phi(y)dy, \forall g\in L^2$.

$\therefore f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ in $L^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your claim is true.  For the proof, consider the following hints:

Let $g_n = \phi_n$ and $g_0 = \phi$ for brevity and define

$$
\Gamma_n : L^1 \to L^2, f \mapsto f \ast g_n. 
$$

By Youngs inequality, these are well-defined with $\Vert \Gamma_n \Vert \leq \Vert g_n\Vert_2 \leq C$. In the last step, I used that weakly convergent sequences are bounded.

Thus, the operator $\Gamma_n$ are uniformly bounded. You want to show $\Gamma_n f \to \Gamma_0 f$ for all $f\in L^1$. By standard density arguments, it suffices to show this for a dense subset of $f$s (by uniform boundedness).

The convergence holds for Schwartz functions $f$, as you can see on the Fourier side (Plancherel), where you have $\hat{g_n} \to \hat{g_0}$ pointwise by the support assumption for the $\phi_n$, so that you can use dominated convergence (note that also by the support assumption you have $g_n$ bounded in $L^1$, so that the Fourier transforms are bounded in $L^\infty$.) Use dominated convergence.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should do it by Fourier transformation.